# does passing parameter with url affect amazon s3 caching?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a file hosted on amazon s3 service `http://www.example.com/tempfile.html`

Now if I pass a parameter with url like `http://www.example.com/tempfile.html?u=2345`

Will this be treated as a different url altogether and I will get no benefit of caching?

Answer (score 0):

> Will this be treated as a different url altogether and I will get no
> benefit of caching?

Generally speaking, adding the [Query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) yields a different URL indeed, which in itself is still fully cacheable accordingly, see section [Side Effects of GET and HEAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.9) (within [Caching in HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13)):

> We note one exception to this rule: since some applications have
> traditionally used GETs and HEADs with query URLs (those containing a
> "?" in the rel_path part) to perform operations with significant side
> effects, caches MUST NOT treat responses to such URIs as fresh unless
> the server provides an explicit expiration time.

This is actually a widely used, though somewhat controversial technique to enforce browsers to replace long living static assets like CSS/JS, see e.g. SCdF's answer to [What is an elegant way to force browsers to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118902/45773) and its comments for an extensive discussion of this and related approaches and the respective pros and cons. The apparently preferred solution for the CSS/JS topic nowadays uses filename fingerprinting rather than adding a query fragment accordingly, as discussed in the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5588394/45773) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/120960/45773) answers there as well.